# Flash message show continuously in code-igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, flash-message

The flash message show continuously in open another page the we complete that event show that event message

Controller

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-danger  text-center"> Some error occured... Try Later!!!...</div>');
redirect('Admin/add_customer');
```

View

```
<h4><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg');?></h4>
```

And we take another page after this event the same msg show in that page, refresh two or more time that will hide in new page ,
Any way to solve this issue ?

Comment: Flashdata will only be available for the next server request, and are then automatically cleared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally flash-data will only be available for the next server request, and are then automatically cleared. so if you refresh the page and if it`s not cached, flash message should disappear.How ever if it`s not working, you could clear session data related to message in view (not encouraged)

```
<h4><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg');
unset($_SESSION['msg']);
?></h4>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue in newer version of php . You can fix it by replacing line 420 in system/libraries/Session/Session.php:

```
elseif ($value < $current_time)
```

with

```
elseif ($value === 'old' || $value < $current_time)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try that type it's work properly and i have used that code in all CI projects.

Controller :

```
if($query){
      $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Sucessful added store');
      redirect($this->redirect);
    }
    else{
      $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Something is wrong. Error!!');
       redirect($this->redirect);
    }
```

View:

```
<?php if ($this->session->flashdata('success')) { ?>

        <div class="alert alert-success">
          <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
            <strong><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('success'); ?></strong>
        </div>

<?php } ?>

<?php if ($this->session->flashdata('error')) { ?>

        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
            <strong><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('error'); ?></strong>
        </div>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

session->flashdata('success')) { ?>

```
    <div class="alert alert-success">
      <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
        <strong><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('success'); ?></strong>
    </div>
```

session->flashdata('error')) { ?>

```
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
        <strong><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('error'); ?></strong>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.